# Change print compiler phase in scala console dynamically

Tags: scala, console

We can start scala console with some predifined compiler phase mode with `-Xprint:typer`, but can it be turned on in the console or changed dynamically within a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4594

and a PR

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2701

For now,

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._, definitions._ also imported    **
** Try  :help, :vals, power.<tab>           **

scala> settings.processArgumentString("-Ylog:typer")
res0: (Boolean, List[String]) = (true,List())

scala> val i = 8
[log typer] [+symbol] method $line in object $read (flags: <method>)
```

But you can't turn it off.